# .NET MVC file exists checking error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is my code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Result(FormCollection form)
{
    String Date = form["date"].ToString();
    String Directory = Date.Replace("-", "");

    //Featch file path
    String RootPath = Properties.Settings.Default.FilePath.ToString();
    String FilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(RootPath, Directory, "Call.Log.txt");
    FilePath = @System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FilePath).ToString();

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(FilePath))
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);

        }
        return null;
    } else
    {
        return View("DirNotFound");
    }

    //return null;
}
```

I'm receiving date as **2015-07-27** from form. And D:\ from **RootPath**. As **FilePath** output I'm getting `D:\\20150727\\Call.Log.txt`. The file is really exists in the directory but I'm getting **false** as `System.IO.File.Exists(FilePath)`. I need your suggestion to fix the issue.

Comment: Does the server have permissions to access that file?

Comment: You shhould use `MapPath` to generate the path in MVC